# How to print out text in beforeAction in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

How to print out data within function beforeAction? I want to make some verification before each action in a controller, therefore if some condition occurs in beforeAction I should print out data and prevent further execution, for example, JSON:

```
[
   status: "error",
   msg: "access denied"
]
```

I try to even inner redirect to another controller, but it doesn't work.

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    if ( ! checkByToken($request->get('token')) && $this->getRoute() != 'web/abonent/token_error') {
        \Yii::$app->runAction('web/abonent/token_error');
        return true;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```

But maybe there an another concept of doing so. I just need to check the condition before any actions and print our result or let the action execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent further execution:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    return false; // key point
}
```

To print out data within beforeAction:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    // set response format = json:
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON; 
    // then, set the response data:
    Yii::$app->response->data = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'msg' => 'access denied'
    ];
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think will be better

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    if ( ! checkByToken($request->get('token')) && $this->getRoute() != 'web/abonent/token_error') {
       $action = 'error';
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```

Action name must be 'actionError'

Comment: Your method looks very tempting to use but in my Yii2 version 2.0.12 it doesn't work. It just still print out controller's actions but not 'error' action.